# How to search/replace expressions with parantheses in emacs?

Tags: search, emacs, replace, latex

I have a bit of Latex code with lots of maths expressions enclosed in \mathrm{}. I'd like to remove the \mathrm{} code around the expressions, preferrably using emacs. For example, I'd like to substitute

```
\mathrm{\gamma \cdot x_0}
```

with

```
\gamma \cdot x_0
```

Removing \mathrm{ only is easy, but I also need to remove the closing bracket. How can I do this in emacs?

Many thanks,

Enno

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use *back references* to tackle this problem. Run

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `query-replace-regexp`

and enter `\\mathrm{\([\a-z0-9_ ]+\)}` at the first prompt, `\1` at the second prompt.

The default keybinding for `query-replace-regexp` is <kbd>C-M-%</kbd>.

The `\1` is a back reference to the first parenthesized group, `\([\a-z0-9_ ]+\)`, in the regexp to replace. This group targets the content between the curly brackets. So what you are saying is that for any occurrence of the regexp to replace you would only like to keep that content.

---

More info on replacing regular expressions can be found [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Replace.html) or in the corresponding `info` node of the Emacs manual.

Comment: Provided there can't be other curly braces nested inside the ones you're matching, you might prefer `{\(.*?\)}` to match the curly braces and their contents, without the need to be specific about what the contents can be. `*?` is the non-greedy version of `*`.

Comment: Maybe the `\mathrm` serves to set units of measurement in roman letters (such as it is the standard) and for any reason you have to change this to normal font. The unit for the velocity is `\frac{m}{s}`. But therewith you already have braces within the `\mathrm{\frac{m}{s}}` argument. Your regexp would match `\mathrm{\frac{m}` in this case which is dangerous. Therefore, I would prefer my answer below which captures the full sexp behind `\mathrm` as last group.

Answer (score 5):

The command `query-replace-regexp` is quite flexible. You can set `replace-re-search-function` to your own search function.
On this basis the following lisp code defines a new command `query-replace-re+sexp` which searches for a regular expression but includes the trailing sexp into the match.

After evaluating the `defun` below you can use `M-x query-replace-re+sexp` as query-replace function. In your example, input as "from"-string `\\\\mathrm` and as "replace-with"-string `\\1`. There, the expression `\\1` refers to the additional subexpression which results from the trailing sexp (without delimiters).

```lisp
(defun re+sexp-search-forward (regexp bound noerror)
  "Search forward for REGEXP (like `re-search-forward')
but with appended sexp."
  (when (re-search-forward regexp bound noerror)
    (let ((md (match-data))
      bsub esub)
      (setq bsub (1+ (scan-sexps (goto-char (scan-sexps (point) 1)) -1))
        esub (1- (point)))
      (setcar (cdr md) (set-marker (make-marker) (point)))
      (setq md (append md (list (set-marker (make-marker) bsub)
                (set-marker (make-marker) esub))))
      (set-match-data md)
      (point))))

(defun query-replace-re+sexp ()
  "Like `query-replace-regexp' but at each match it includes the trailing sexps
into the match as an additional subexpression (the last one)."
  (interactive)
  (let ((replace-re-search-function 're+sexp-search-forward)) (call-interactively 'query-replace-regexp)))
```

This should be a quite nice feature. Not only for the replacement of LaTeX constructs like

```
\mathrm{\frac{\gamma}{x_0}}
```

with

```
\frac{\gamma}{x_0}
```

but also for replacements in program texts. For an example the replacement of function calls like

```
doSomethingUseless(x+somethingUseful(y))
```

with

```
x+somethingUseful(y)
```