# emacs regular expression how to get specific columns

Tags: regex, emacs

I have the following text file:

**Input text file:**

```
<Person FirstName='Steve' LastName='Smith' Phone='555-12345' Title='Mr.' BirthDate='1950-01-01' />

<Person FirstName='Lin' LastName='Dan' Phone='555-12345' Title='Mr.' BirthDate='1950-01-01' />
```

I want to get the following:

**expect output text:**

```
Steve Smith
Lin Dan
```

Comment: Don't forget that if you want to test out Regular Expressions in Emacs, you can use `M-x regexp-builder`

Comment: To add to the great answer by @Andreas Röhler, Emacs might or might not be the right tool for this, depending on the use case. How will this fit into something bigger? Does a command-line tool make more sense?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regexp with *back references* for this:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `query-replace-regexp`

<kbd>RET</kbd> `.+?'\([A-Za-z]+\)'.+?'\([A-Za-z]+\)'.+`

<kbd>RET</kbd> `\1 \2`

The trick is to write a regexp that matches the whole line, while putting the content that you want to keep into *parenthesized groups* that you can reference in the output you want to generate.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20515314/1199226) answer to a similar question for a bit more info about back references and a link to relevant portions of the Emacs manual.

---

**EDIT:** A shorter version of the regexp to replace that also works for the example input you gave would be `.+?'\(.+?\)'.+?'\(.+?\)'.+`.

Answer (score 1):

Giving another answer still, being as specific as possible makes regular expressions more reliable. You want the contents of precise slots, so let's use its names:

```
(defun my-name-slots ()
  (interactive)
  (while (re-search-forward "FirstName='\\([^']+\\)'[ \t]+LastName='\\([^']+\\)'" nil t 1)
    (message "%s %s" (match-string-no-properties 1) (match-string-no-properties 2) )))
```

As `(match-string-no-properties 1) (match-string-no-properties 2)` holding the output looked for,

```
(list ...)
```

at the end of the function would return it as a list.